# Find a random variable $X$ such that $\mathbb{E}e^{\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{t^2}}> \mathbb{E} e^{X^2/t^2}$

Tags: probability

Find a random variable $X$ such that $\mathbb{E}e^{\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{t^2}}> \mathbb{E} e^{\frac{X^2}{t^2}}$ where $t$ is chosen such that $\mathbb{E} e^{\frac{X^2}{t^2}}\ge2$.

Attempt:

I have tried to define $X$ as Bernoulli but it does not work. The intuition here I think is to somehow use convexity of exponential function because if we bound it with a linear function then this will not work.

Comment: I think this is somewhat instructive to work out, so if it’s any assurance, let me just say that it is indeed possible to find an example that takes on just two values $\pm x$. In fact, take $x=\sqrt{\ln 2}$ so that $t=1$. Now it’s just a matter of finding the right probability between them